# specify db password in ant build file

Tags: hibernate, ant

my webapp has a hibernate config file that specifies db password as follows:

```
 <property name="hibernate.connection.password">p1ssw2rd</property>
```

it also has an ant build file, is it possible to specify the db password at build time and then pass it to hibernate?

```
    <target name="init-development">

      <property name="databasePassword" value="xxxx"/>
    </target>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create template hibernate config with password label like this:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">@@HIBER_PASSWORD@@</property>
```

and when ant starts a build, copy template config over real hibernate config, applying replacement password label with real db password specified in build.xml. 
It is like that:

```
<copy file="${src.dir}/hibernate-config.xml.tpl"
         tofile="${src.dir}/hibernate-config.xml">
    <filterchain>
           <replacetokens>
               <token key="@@HIBER_PASSWORD@@"
                      value="${databasePassword}"/>
           </replacetokens>
    </filterchain>
</copy>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the section
`<replacetokens>
               <token key="@@HIBER_PASSWORD@@"
                      value="${databasePassword}"/>
           </replacetokens>`

for replaceString

:D
It works